What is being called/requested when running Azure Functions locally
The issue we are facing is that when we run Azure Functions locally, we get stuck up to maybe 500seconds, on the screen(see screenshot). then shows a series of timeout errors.
Note that this only happens when I am at work, meaning there is some issue with the security/network in the office. Because when I run it using tethered mobile data or when I run it at home on my wifi, it runs smoothly. After which the problem is solved for a long time, but we have a lot of developers who is having this issue. The work-around works well but I need to report this to the network team on why it is happening and how we can whitelist something. Also note that before we figured the work-around, we tried downloading: func_cli_x64 , both from that site and using npm or chocolatey. All are having long download times and sometimes unresponsive.
Summary of question: What could be blocking or hindering the azure function test locally run, it seems a network issue as it works when I am using my home or personal internet.


My settings are below:
tasks.json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "func",
            "label": "func: host start",
            "command": "host start",
            "problemMatcher": "$func-node-watch",
            "isBackground": false,
            "dependsOn": "npm install (functions)"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "npm install (functions)",
            "command": "npm install"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "npm prune (functions)",
            "command": "npm prune --production",
            "problemMatcher": []
        }
    ]
}

local.settings.json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=false"
  },
  "Host":{
    "LocalHttpPort": 3000,
    "CORS": "*"
  }  
}

